# Large Data: Storage and Query

Tags: database

There is a similar question [Large data - storage and query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352895/large-data-storage-and-query)
But I think my question is even more harder.

I have a huge data set, to simplify the problem, suppose each record has 3 fields,

Date, Location, Object

means on which day, object visits which place.

For each day there can be 50 million new records. I need to keep 100 days data.

And queries are like these:

1. Given a date range, list all the objects who have visited specific location X;
2. Given a date range, list all the locations a specific object have visited.

How should I design on this? Is it possible to give a solution? Any tools should I have a try? Can I use mongodb or hadoop?

And what's more, the query should not take much long time since it will be queried from front end.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The queries you describe are perfectly suited for a relational database. Whilst you will have a large amount of data, the queries lend themselves well to a fairly simple index scheme.

Some commercial databases have geo-spatial extensions which would allow you to extend the queries to "given a date range, tell me which objects have been in within 20 kilometers of location x".

It also seems that whilst you have a large number of rows, the actual data size is fairly limited; it's not unreasonable to expect it to fit into memory on a high-end machine.

Most database systems can handle very large tables - there's no logical limit to the number of records an RDBMS holds, though there are obviously practical limits. Oracle has a solid reputation for performance with large data sets, though it's definitely worth getting an experienced Oracle DBA to help. A common strategy when handling huge amounts of data is "[sharding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_%28database_architecture%29)" - putting different records in different tables and/or servers. If all your queries are date-based, you might put the data for each month on different physical servers, for instance.

I'd start with an RDBMS, create a test data set to work out if it meets your scalability needs by running and tuning sample queries. Tune the hardware, and add more if you can afford to.

I don't think you will get much benefit from Hadoop - you're not doing much processing, you're just searching a large dataset.

MongoDB is designed to work with document-style data; your data seems relational in nature, rather than being a document. You could build this in MongoDB, but I'm not sure you'd get much benefit.

Comment: If use relational DB, my question is for typical database like sybase, db2, do they have a limitation on records in a table? For my question I will have billions of records finally.

Comment: Yes, an RDBMS should be able to handle that number of records - I've updated the answer. You may need to get a DBA to help tune your database, though.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a try!

Answer (score 0):

That problem is not as hard as it sounds. You need two indexes:

```
(Location, Date, Object)
(Object, Date, Location)
```

Those two indexes satisfy your queries optimally. There will be no inherent scalability limit that you need to worry about.

You might consider partitioning on `Date` so that you can drop old partitions efficiently.