# mysql master/slave failover

Tags: mysql, high-availability, failover

Is there any product that make mysql master/slave failover process easier? something that can happen automatically, rather than manually fix it.

Answer (score 1):

[... a bit later ... ;)

What are you calling "easier" ?
There is pretty much solutions with MySQL :

- MySQL Cluster, with NDB Engine (High availability solution but some limitations : no foreign keys)
- MySQL Master / Slave with their own replication system
- MySQL replicated via DRBD and heartbeat.

There is a lot of material on this subject : 
[Failover support for a DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304968/failover-support-for-a-db) and even more here : [Scaling solutions for MySQL (Replication, Clustering)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189903/scaling-solutions-for-mysql-replication-clustering)

MySQL cluster in an out of the box solution, but replication is not very difficult to set up.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The actual failover bit can be managed with heartbeat (part of the Linux HA project; http://linux-ha.org/), and I'm told that there's some tools in the MySQL Enterprise grab bag that helps with managing replication, although I've never used it myself.

Comment: Deploy MySQL as Master/Master mode. Then working with Linux-HA on top.