# How to scale MySQL with multiple machines?

Tags: mysql, performance, scaling

I have a web app running LAMP. We recently have an increase in load and is now looking at solutions to scale. Scaling apache is pretty easy we are just going to have multiple multiple machines hosting it and round robin the incoming traffic.

However, each instance of apache will talk with MySQL and eventually MySQL will be overloaded. How to scale MySQL across multiple machines in this setup? I have already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189903/scaling-solutions-for-mysql-replication-clustering) but specifically we need the updates from the DB available immediately so I don't think replication is a good strategy here? Also hopefully this can be done with minimal code change.

PS. We have around a 1:1 read-write ratio.

Answer (score 25):

There're only two strategies: replication and sharding. Replication comes often in place when you have less write and much read traffic, so you can redirect the reads to many slaves, with the pitfall of lots of replication traffic with the time and a probability for inconsitency.

With sharding you shard your database tables across multiple machines (called functional sharding), which makes especially joins much harder. If this doenst fit anymore you also need to shard you rows across multiple machines, but this is no fun and depends a sharding layer implemented between you application and the database.

Document oriented databases or column stores do this work for you, but they are currently optimized for OLAP not for OLTP.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the application backend (i.e. how the PKs, transactions and insert IDs are handled), you might consider MASTER-MASTER replication with different auto_increment setups. This can be tricky and needs to be thoroughly tested but it can work.

Also, in new MySQL 5.6 there is a GTID (Global Transaction Identifier) that generally helps a lot in keeping the replication in sync, especially in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [MySQL Performance Blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/). Maybe you'll find something useful.

Answer (score 0):

Well... good luck scaling all those writes to a real large scale. The database engine becomes the bottleneck, too many locks and buffers mgmt and stuff...

The only way I found that really works is scale out, sharding, unfortunately sharding is not provided for MySQL "out of the box" (like in some NoSQLs such as Mongo). [ScaleBase](http://www.scalebase.com/products/product-architecture/) (disclaimer: I work there) is a maker of a complete scale-out solution an "automatic sharding machine" if you like. ScaleBae analyzes your data and SQL stream, splits the data across DB nodes, route commands and aggregates results in runtime – so you won’t have to!