# mysql server multiple instances

Tags: mysql

Hi I have a server machine where I have installed mysql server. 
Now my tables are really getting bigger so I have decided to split my data. 
I am thinking of using 2 instances of mysql server one instance will take only 1 days request and the other server will take request where the data requested is for a lot of days.

My question is what are the ways of running multiple mysql server
I read online there are 2 ways of doing that
1) Changing the my.cnf file with different port numbers and data directory
2) Configuring the mysql installation and then installing the new mysql with new mysql.

Which is the best way of doing it?

Comment: take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189903/scaling-solutions-for-mysql-replication-clustering Eran Galperin gathered a lot information how things should be done

Answer (score 0):

absolutely the first way. or you can use command line argument to specify the port number and data directory.

`mysqld --port=3307 --datadir=/var/mysql/data3307 [other options]`